# How to stepwise approximate f(x) using Euler's method given f'(x)

Tags: python, calculus

Here is a problem from the Ohio State online calculus course.  Easy enough but this old guy wants  to write a Python  program instead of solving it longhand.  Butting my head against the wall:

f′(x)=−0.5x^2 − 0.5f(x) and which satisfies

f(−3)=0.

Use repeated linear approximation (otherwise known as Euler's Method) to approximate the value of this function at x=−1

using a step size of 1/2

```
def fprime(a):
    return -.5*(a**2) - .5*f(a)

h = .5
f(-3) = 0

# So f'(-3) = -.5*(-3)^2 - .5*(0) = -4.5
# And since f(a+h) = f(a) + h*f'(a):
# f(-3 + .5) = f(-3) + .5*(-4.5) = -2.25 which leads to:
# f'(-2.5) = see fprime above . . . .
# repeat steps to solve for f(-1)
```

How do I define f(a) without referencing itself and then structure the loop?
I rarely try to program and wish I had the time and brains to really learn how.  Thank you for your patience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is to change your definition of `fprime` so that it accepts a `y` argument, so you can pass it the `y` values you're calculating inside the Euler integration function.

```
def euler(df, x0, y0, dx, x1):
    x, y = x0, y0
    while x < x1:
        y = y + dx * df(x, y)
        x += dx
    return y

def fprime(x, y):
    return -0.5 * (x**2) - 0.5 * y

x0 = -3.0
y0 = 0.0
x1 = -1.0

for h in (0.5, 0.05, 0.001, 1E-6):
    print euler(fprime, x0, y0, h, x1)
```

**output**

```
-3.140625
-2.36751792506
-2.33223301294
-2.33149760872
```

As you can see, the value calculated with `h` = 0.5 isn't very accurate. Smaller `h` gives better values, but it's a bit slow doing a million steps. :) Euler integration is straight-forward, but it's not very fast, or accurate: there are much better ways.

FWIW, here's a more accurate value I calculated using the 3rd-party [mpmath](http://mpmath.org/) arbitrary-precision mathematics module:

`-2.3314962060281726737298106653176348`

---

And here's the analytical solution:

> f(x) = -x² + 4x - 8 + 29 exp(-(x+3)/2)

Or in Python

```
f = lambda x: -x**2 + 4*x - 8 + 29 * exp(-0.5*(x+3))
```

I'll leave the details of the calculus as "an exercise for the reader". :) But it's fairly easy to check that it's correct via differentiation, and substitution of the boundary values.

Comment: **Thank you @PM**.  I'm constantly wowed by the generosity of folks like you helping folks like me.  Thanks for the lesson.

Comment: @user3308780: My pleasure! FWIW, I've just solved it analytically; I'll add the equation to my answer shortly.